# For Loop Fails on HTML -- PHP

Tags: php, html, for-loop

A simple for loop is failing to output HTML?????

```
    for ($i = 0; $i <= ($fill_in_cells_1 - 1); ++$i) {
        $why .= 'why';
        $fill_in_cells_1_display .= '<td width="35px" style="background-color: red"></td>';
    }
```

When I echo $why, I get the proper number of "why's".  When I echo $fill_in_cells_1_display, it's blank.  If I take out the < and > it echos properly.

My question: Why?

Comment: I assume this is in  <tr> within a <table>... try a &nbsp; as the content of your <td>

Comment: have you checked the source code, as nothing will actually print on screen?

Comment: `var_dump` instead of `echo` to make sure it's not a display issue.

Comment: I'd change your quotes to this-> "<td width='35px' style='background-color: red'></td>"

Comment: are $why and $fill_in_cells_1_display already defined as blank strings before the for loop? the .= needs something to concatenate the first string to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cells that are returned will be empty, so echoing the table will not work. Try to give the cells a test value.

When you leave the < and >, the var value is not recognized as HTML and will be echoed like text.

Comment: Yup.  That was it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($fill_in_cells_1_display);
```

You tried this in your browser, so please see @Pieter's answer.  Had you tried this in your terminal/command line you would have seen expected result.